# Discount vs Discounts

Tags: word-usage, grammar, word-choice

I would like to convey discount available for the single product. which of the below one is right?

`Discounts available`   OR  `Discount available`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you talking about a single discount then it should be singular "**discount**" if you mention more than one discount then plural "**discounts**"

Take into account that a single product has only one discount. I've never heard about two discounts being placed on a product, however, it is possible.

Comment: The case of multiple discounts would be if different customers in different situations got different discounts.  For example, there might be one discount for senior citizens, and a different one for children under six years old.  Or there might be a discount for buying five of an item, and an even larger discount if you buy more than twenty.  If all discounts are the same, however, then use the singular.